# Meio de fazer uma comparação entre três variáveis

Tags: php, condição

Estou precisando fazer uma comparações entre três variáveis no meu código PHP.

```
if($a == $b == $c) {
   return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Tenho muitas ideias de como fazer isso, mas quero saber qual a melhor maneira de conseguir esse resultado.

Comment: O que é a "melhor maneira"? A mais rápida? A mais legível?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

A solução mais simples, direta e objetiva é

```php
return ($a === $b && $a === $c);
```

caso você queira apenas comparar valores, e não os tipos, pode usar assim:

```php
return ($a == $b && $a == $c);
```

neste ultimo caso, usando `==` em vez de `===`

**Um comentário:**

Na pergunta você usou este if:

```php
if($a == $b == $c) {
   return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

Quando você usa uma condição lógica, como `($a == $b)`, **o resultado ja é *true* ou *false***. Num caso desses você pode simplesmente retornar o resultado com `return ( $a==$b )`, pois o if é totalmente redundante e desnecessário, visto que a comparação ja é a resposta desejada.

Answer (score 7):

Acho que a mais eficiente é:

```
if ($a === $b && $a === $c) {
    return true;
}
return false;
```

Lembrando que `==` testa se as variáveis têm valores equivalentes (por exemplo, um `0` equivale a um `null`) e o `===` testa se as variáveis são do mesmo tipo E possuem o mesmo valor.

Answer (score 6):

É como você fez, porém tem que testar uma coisa por vez e usar o operador equivalente ao `E`/`AND`.

```
// Nota: bloco de código alterado. Espero que da próxima vez os colegas
//       estejam mais preocupados com o foco da questão e comentários
//       relacionados a performance e redução de erros do que ficar preso
//       estilo de código, em especial quando for apenas uma cópia do código
//       original e não tenha sido solicitado um regractoring completo
if ($a === $b && $b === $c) {
   // Bloco de código
} else {
  // Outro bloco de código
}
```

Além do fato de que há diferença entre o operador igual `==`, que diz que os valores são iguais, e o operador idêntico `===` que além de ter o valor igual, o tipo é o mesmo, tem mais uma coisa bem importante na ordem dos operadores:

> Ao usar o operador `&&`, sempre ponha a condição menos custosa em primeiro lugar, pois se ela falhar a segunda nem será testada

E outra coisa bem importante

> Cuide a ordem das operações com `&&` pois ela fará diferença se uma operação só pode ocorrer se a anterior ocorreu antes, ou se uma das operações gerará erro que a outra não for verdadeira.

As duas informações na caixas amarela costumam ser esquecidas ou só são percebidas tarde, quando o desenvolvedor percebe que houve alguma mensagem de erro no sistema.

Comment: Quem deu -1 pode explicar o motivo? O que está errado na minha resposta?

Comment: Eu manti ela porque a pergunta do autor foi sobre os condicionais testar igualdade sobre mais de dois operadores, não sobre return, e expliquei diferenças bem mais importantes para o foco da questão que envolvem **performance** e **redução de erros de execução**. Da próxima vez que  for negativar resposta de outra pessoa a uma pergunta que você também respondeu, a não ser que alguém já tenha reclamado e você dê um +1 no comentário da pessoa, comente porque deu -1. É agressivo esse comportamento. Tenha em mente ao pensar nisso de novo com outros.

Comment: A resposta está boa +1. Creio que, se já houve confusão do AP ao usar `$a == $b == $c`, então era importante sim explicar sobre o uso do operador `&`.

Answer (score 2):

A maneira mais fácil de fazer isso é separando as comparações, dessa forma você vai conseguir saber exatamente qual está dando `true` ou `false`.
Exemplo:

```
<?php
if(($a == $b) && ($a == $c)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
?>
```

Dessa forma se você precisar conferir cada uma das comparações separadamente depois fica bem mais fácil.