# Sinal idêntico "===" é usado apenas em PHP? Por que?

Tags: php, terminologia, operadores

Durante meus estudos em linguagem C e Java, eu sempre me deparei com o sinal `"="` de *atribuição* e o sinal `"=="` sendo de *igualdade*. Porém, estou estudando PHP agora e me deparei com o sinal `"==="` de ***idêntico***.

Minhas dúvidas são:

- O Sinal de idêntico é usado só em PHP? Se sim, por que?
- Se não, quais linguagens possuem esse sinal?
- Caso C e Java o possuam, por que não é tão conhecido/ensinado junto com os outros sinais?

Comment: [Operador == e === em JavaScript](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7/91). Linguagem com tipagem fraca usam esse operadora para saber se a comparação de valor e tipo são iguais em linguagens de tipagem forte não precisa.

Comment: Relacionada ou Duplicata? : [Meio de fazer uma comparação entre três variáveis](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5335/meio-de-fazer-uma-compara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-entre-tr%C3%AAs-vari%C3%A1veisvariáveis)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> O sinal de idêntico é usado só em PHP? Se não, quais linguagens possuem esse sinal?

Não, é usado pelo menos em [JavaScript também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/7/101), talvez em outras linguagens de [tipagem dinâmica e fraca](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101).

O `==` compara os valores no melhor esforço possível, se os tipos de cada operando forem diferentes a linguagem tenta compatibilizá-los para conseguir fazer a comparação. Isso pode trazer [resultados indesejados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80767/101).

O `===` considera o tipo e nenhuma coerção é feita. Se os tipos forem diferentes já é garantindo que o resultado será diferente e o valor só é avaliado se os tipos forem iguais.

> Se sim, por que?

PHP é uma linguagem de *script*, foi feita para "facilitar" a criação rápida de código e o programador não ter que se preocupar com certos detalhes, então isso fazia sentido. Hoje a linguagem tenta deixar de ser *script*, mas precisa manter compatibilidade, então fica essa coisa meio esquizofrênica.

> Caso C e Java o possuam, porque não é tão conhecido/ensinado junto com os outros sinais?

Isso é características de linguagens de tipagem fraca onde um valor pode ser passar como se fosse de outro tipo. Java não é assim.

C até é assim, mas de um jeito um pouco diferente, normalmente não se tenta fazer conversões, ele apenas tenta acessar e memória de forma bruta. Nunca acharam necessário ter um operador de "idêntico" em C porque a filosofia da linguagem é deixar acessar de qualquer forma. Mas hoje quase todos compiladores, pelo menos opcionalmente, produzem *warnings* quando isso ocorre forçando o programador usar um *cast* para indicar que a intenção é usar um tipo como se fosse outro.

É muito raro uma linguagem ter tipagem estática e fraca, C é assim porque é considerado um Assembly portável.

Mesmo linguagens de tipagem dinâmica optam por tipagem forte, caso de [Python](https://www.python.org), [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), [Harbour](https://harbour.github.io/), etc.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).