# Como ler e interpretar um arquivo JSON com PHP?

Tags: php, json, revisão-de-código

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em PHP, na qual estou lendo um arquivo JSON (contendo diversas notas fiscais eletrônicas) e preciso guardar algumas tags contidas neste arquivo JSON em variáveis.

Comecei a estudar PHP a pouco tempo, atualmente estou conseguindo ler as tags Discriminacao do arquivo JSON e fiz uma lógica bem inicial com alguns if's usando o strpos.

Eu preciso ler a string inteira da tag Discriminacao e checar se se a mesma contém o termo "SUPORTE", "DESENVOLVIMENTO" ou "MANUTENÇÃO". E se conter o termo específico, salvar este resultado em uma variável.

- A minha lógica está correta? Tem algo que possa ser feito para otimizar alguma coisa no meu código?

**Segue o arquivo JSON:**

```
{
"ConsultarNfseResposta": {
"ListaNfse": {
  "CompNfse": [
    {
      "Nfse": {
        "InfNfse": {
          "Numero": "12651",
          "CodigoVerificacao": "ECSV-FGRD",
          "DataEmissao": "2017-07-25T17:51:12",
          "NaturezaOperacao": "1",
          "OptanteSimplesNacional": "1",
          "IncentivadorCultural": "2",
          "Competencia": "2017-07-25T00:00:00",
          "Servico": {
            "Valores": {
              "ValorServicos": "2350",
              "IssRetido": "2",
              "BaseCalculo": "2350",
              "Aliquota": "0.02",
              "ValorLiquidoNfse": "2350"
            },
            "ItemListaServico": "0107",
            "CodigoTributacaoMunicipio": "6209100",
            "Discriminacao": "TAXA: MANUTENÇÃO",
            "CodigoMunicipio": "2611606"
          },
          "PrestadorServico": {
            "IdentificacaoPrestador": {
              "Cnpj": "41069964000173",
              "InscricaoMunicipal": "2427745"
            },
            "RazaoSocial": "INFORMATICA LTDA",
            "Endereco": {
              "Endereco": "RUA 241",
              "Numero": "241",
              "Bairro": "Exemplo",
              "CodigoMunicipio": "2611606",
              "Uf": "PE",
              "Cep": "52030190"
            },
            "Contato": {
              "Telefone": "33254854",
              "Email": "exemplo@ex.com.br"
            }
          },
          "TomadorServico": {
            "IdentificacaoTomador": {
              "CpfCnpj": {
                "Cnpj": "00085803000196"
              }
            },
            "RazaoSocial": "EXEMPLO - AFBR",
            "Endereco": {
              "Endereco": "ST 06",
              "Bairro": "Asa Sul",
              "CodigoMunicipio": "5300108",
              "Uf": "DF",
              "Cep": "15425845211"
            },
            "Contato": {
              "Email": "exemplo@gmail.com"
            }
          },
          "OrgaoGerador": {
            "CodigoMunicipio": "2611606",
            "Uf": "PE"
          }      
        }
      }
    },

    {
      "Nfse": {
        "InfNfse": {
          "Numero": "12658",
          "CodigoVerificacao": "ECSV-NMBH",
          "DataEmissao": "2017-07-25T17:51:12",
          "NaturezaOperacao": "1",
          "OptanteSimplesNacional": "1",
          "IncentivadorCultural": "2",
          "Competencia": "2017-07-24T00:00:00",
          "Servico": {
            "Valores": {
              "ValorServicos": "9500",
              "IssRetido": "2",
              "BaseCalculo": "2350",
              "Aliquota": "0.02",
              "ValorLiquidoNfse": "2350"
            },
            "ItemListaServico": "0107",
            "CodigoTributacaoMunicipio": "6209100",
            "Discriminacao": "TAXA: DESENVOLVIMENTO",
            "CodigoMunicipio": "2611606"
          },
          "PrestadorServico": {
            "IdentificacaoPrestador": {
              "Cnpj": "41069964000173",
              "InscricaoMunicipal": "2427745"
            },
            "RazaoSocial": "INFORMATICA LTDA",
            "Endereco": {
              "Endereco": "RUA 241",
              "Numero": "241",
              "Bairro": "Exemplo",
              "CodigoMunicipio": "2611606",
              "Uf": "PE",
              "Cep": "52030190"
            },
            "Contato": {
              "Telefone": "33254854",
              "Email": "exemplo@exemplo.com.br"
            }
          },
          "TomadorServico": {
            "IdentificacaoTomador": {
              "CpfCnpj": {
                "Cnpj": "958451368500014"
              }
            },
            "RazaoSocial": "EXEMPLO - ATBR",
            "Endereco": {
              "Endereco": "ST 06",
              "Bairro": "Asa Sul",
              "CodigoMunicipio": "5300108",
              "Uf": "DF",
              "Cep": "15425845211"
            },
            "Contato": {
              "Email": "exemplo@gmail.com"
            }
          },
          "OrgaoGerador": {
            "CodigoMunicipio": "2611606",
            "Uf": "PE"
          }
        }
      }
    },

    {
      "Nfse": {
        "InfNfse": {
          "Numero": "12659",
          "CodigoVerificacao": "ECSV-HFGS",
          "DataEmissao": "2017-07-25T17:51:12",
          "NaturezaOperacao": "1",
          "OptanteSimplesNacional": "1",
          "IncentivadorCultural": "2",
          "Competencia": "2017-07-25T00:00:00",
          "Servico": {
            "Valores": {
              "ValorServicos": "7600",
              "IssRetido": "2",
              "BaseCalculo": "7600",
              "Aliquota": "0.02",
              "ValorLiquidoNfse": "7600"
            },
            "ItemListaServico": "0107",
            "CodigoTributacaoMunicipio": "6209100",
            "Discriminacao": "TAXA: SUPORTE",
            "CodigoMunicipio": "2611606"
          },
          "PrestadorServico": {
            "IdentificacaoPrestador": {
              "Cnpj": "41069964000173",
              "InscricaoMunicipal": "2427745"
            },
            "RazaoSocial": "INFORMATICA LTDA",
            "Endereco": {
              "Endereco": "RUA 241",
              "Numero": "241",
              "Bairro": "Exemplo",
              "CodigoMunicipio": "2611606",
              "Uf": "PE",
              "Cep": "52030190"
            },
            "Contato": {
              "Telefone": "33254854",
              "Email": "exemplo@exemplo.com.br"
            }
          },
          "TomadorServico": {
            "IdentificacaoTomador": {
              "CpfCnpj": {
                "Cnpj": "95621548745210"
              }
            },
            "RazaoSocial": "EXEMPLO - NOBR",
            "Endereco": {
              "Endereco": "ST 06",
              "Bairro": "Asa Sul",
              "CodigoMunicipio": "5300108",
              "Uf": "DF",
              "Cep": "15425845211"
            },
            "Contato": {
              "Email": "exemplo@gmail.com"
            }
          },
          "OrgaoGerador": {
            "CodigoMunicipio": "2611606",
            "Uf": "PE"
          }         
        }
       }
      }
     ]
    }
   }
  }
```

**E segue também o que eu já fiz com o PHP:**

```
<?php

$json_data = json_decode(file_get_contents('arquivo.json'));

foreach ($json_data->ConsultarNfseResposta->ListaNfse->CompNfse as $data) {

    echo '<br>Número da nota: ' .$data->Nfse->InfNfse->Numero;
    echo '<br>Valor da nota: ' .$data->Nfse->InfNfse->Servico->Valores->ValorServicos;
    echo '<br>CNPJ do cliente: ' .$data->Nfse->InfNfse->TomadorServico->IdentificacaoTomador->CpfCnpj->Cnpj;
    echo '<br>Discriminação do serviço: ' .$data->Nfse->InfNfse->Servico->Discriminacao;
    echo '<br>';

    $stringSuporte = 'SUPORTE';
    $stringManutencao = 'MANUTENÇÃO';
    $stringDesenvolvimento = 'DESENVOLVIMENTO';


    $posSuporte = strpos($data->Nfse->InfNfse->Servico->Discriminacao, $stringSuporte);
    $posManutencao = strpos($data->Nfse->InfNfse->Servico->Discriminacao, $stringManutencao);
    $posDesenvolvimento = strpos($data->Nfse->InfNfse->Servico->Discriminacao, $stringDesenvolvimento);

    if ($posSuporte == true) {
        $servSuporte = $data->Nfse->InfNfse->Servico->Discriminacao;
        echo '<b>String encontrada: </b>' .$servSuporte;
        echo '<br>';
    } 

    if ($posManutencao == true) {
        $servManutencao = $data->Nfse->InfNfse->Servico->Discriminacao;
        echo '<b>String encontrada: </b>' .$servManutencao;
        echo '<br>';
    } 

    if ($posDesenvolvimento == true) {
        $servDesenvolvimento = $data->Nfse->InfNfse->Servico->Discriminacao;
        echo '<b>String encontrada: </b>' .$servDesenvolvimento;
        echo '<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

**O output atualmente do meu programa está resultando o seguinte:**

```
Número da nota: 12651
Valor da nota: 2350
CNPJ do cliente: 00085803000196
Discriminação do serviço: TAXA: MANUTENÇÃO
String encontrada: TAXA: MANUTENÇÃO

Número da nota: 12658
Valor da nota: 9500
CNPJ do cliente: 958451368500014
Discriminação do serviço: TAXA: DESENVOLVIMENTO
String encontrada: TAXA: DESENVOLVIMENTO

Número da nota: 12659
Valor da nota: 7600
CNPJ do cliente: 95621548745210
Discriminação do serviço: TAXA: SUPORTE
String encontrada: TAXA: SUPORTE
```

Comment: `Discriminação do serviço` sempre tem `TAXA: ... algo` ou aquele TAXA pode variar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No lugar de [`strpos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) pode usar [`strstr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) para pegar a última parte da string e comparar o valor do loop com array `$tipos` com ajuda de [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

```
$tipos = array('SUPORTE', 'MANUTENÇÃO', 'DESENVOLVIMENTO');

foreach ($json_data->ConsultarNfseResposta->ListaNfse->CompNfse as $data) {
    echo '<br>Número da nota: ' .$data->Nfse->InfNfse->Numero;
    echo '<br>Valor da nota: ' .$data->Nfse->InfNfse->Servico->Valores->ValorServicos;
    echo '<br>CNPJ do cliente: ' .$data->Nfse->InfNfse->TomadorServico->IdentificacaoTomador->CpfCnpj->Cnpj;
    echo '<br>Discriminação do serviço: ' .$data->Nfse->InfNfse->Servico->Discriminacao;
    echo '<br>';

    $tipoAtual = strstr($data->Nfse->InfNfse->Servico->Discriminacao, ' ');

    if(in_array($tipoAtual, $tipos)){
        printf('<b>String encontrada: </b> %s <br>', $data->Nfse->InfNfse->Servico->Discriminacao);
    }
}
```

**Explicação:**

Utilizar `strpost()` sem tomar os devidos cuidados é uma tremenda furada, pois ele retorna a posição em que a string passada foi encontrada. Isso significa que se ela for a zero seu código gera um falso positivo. Veja esse exemplo clássico:

```
$pos = strpos('X-salada', 'X');

if($pos == true){
    echo 'tem';
}else{
    echo 'não tem';
}
```

A saída é `não tem`. Normalmente (em linguagens com tipagem forte) não se compara booleanos com `true` ou `false`, simplemente se omite a comparação passa-se a variável/expressão direto, então usar o operador `==` não é o correto, nesse caso use o `!==` ou `===` pois ele compara o valor e o tipo.

```
$pos = strpos('X-salada', 'X');

if($pos !== false){
    echo 'tem';
}else{
    echo 'não tem';
}
```

Os três ifs dentro do forech fazem a mesma coisa imprimem algo o que muda é a comparação um `||` (OU) já é o suficiente para elimina-los.

Duplicação de código:

```
if ($posSuporte == true) {
    $servSuporte = $data->Nfse->InfNfse->Servico->Discriminacao;
    echo '<b>String encontrada: </b>' .$servSuporte;
    echo '<br>';
} 

if ($posManutencao == true) {
    $servManutencao = $data->Nfse->InfNfse->Servico->Discriminacao;
    echo '<b>String encontrada: </b>' .$servManutencao;
    echo '<br>';
} 

if ($posDesenvolvimento == true) {
    $servDesenvolvimento = $data->Nfse->InfNfse->Servico->Discriminacao;
    echo '<b>String encontrada: </b>' .$servDesenvolvimento;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Pode virar algo simples como:

```
if($data->Nfse->InfNfse->Servico->Discriminacao == 'TAXA: SUPORTE' ||
   $data->Nfse->InfNfse->Servico->Discriminacao == 'TAXA: MANUTENÇÃO' ||
   $data->Nfse->InfNfse->Servico->Discriminacao == 'TAXA: DESENVOLVIMENTO')
{
    echo '<b>String encontrada: </b>' . $data->Nfse->InfNfse->Servico->Discriminacao .'<br>';
}
```

Relaciondas:

[Sinal idêntico “===” é usado apenas em PHP? Por quê?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/186885/91)

Comment: Muito boa a sua explicação rray. Recentemente eu dei uma modificada no meu código, mas acabei mantendo o strpos, depois de inúmeros testes, a aplicação ta funcionando do jeito esperado. Qualquer problema, eu posso modificar a lógica e ir pelo caminho que você mencionou acima. Muito obrigado!!