# Ler/Pesquisar informação dentro de um Json com PHP

Tags: php, json, api

Estou começando agora com as consultas mais complexas dentro do PHP. 
Como sempre joguei WoW decidi aprender um pouco sobre API com o PHP utilizando a API da Blizzard que me fornece algumas informações.

Depois de muito pesquisar consegui puxar as informações pra dentro de uma tabela, mas me surgiu uma dúvida: utilizando a pesquisa dos pets como exemplo, e se eu quisesse que a minha lista me trouxesse somente os pets com o level maior que 10 (pets->collected->stats->level)

Segue abaixo o código de como ele esta retornando uma tabela com todos os pets e algumas informações

a url completa do json é: https://us.api.battle.net/wow/character/Goldrinn/Lokinhaa?fields=pets&locale=pt_BR&apikey=3ps9yqk69mhjhy435m8sq4razamkwy25

```
<?php


$type = 'character';
$reino = 'Goldrinn';
$char = 'Lokinhaa';
$language = 'pt_BR';
$fields = 'pets';
$api_key = '3ps9yqk69mhjhy435m8sq4razamkwy25';

$url = "https://us.api.battle.net/wow/$type/$reino/$char?fields=$fields&locale=$language&apikey=$api_key"; // path to your JSON file
$data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
$characters = json_decode($data, true); // decode the JSON feed
$pets = $characters['pets']['collected'];

?>

<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Pet</th>
            <th>Spell</th>
            <th>Level</th>
            <th>Health</th>
            <th>Power</th>
            <th>Speed</th>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach ($pets as $pet) : ?>
        <tr>
            <td> <?php echo $pet['name']; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $pet['spellId']; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $pet['stats']['level']; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $pet['stats']['health']; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $pet['stats']['power']; ?> </td>
            <td> <?php echo $pet['stats']['speed']; ?> </td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

?>
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Como ler e interpretar um arquivo JSON com PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/235598/como-ler-e-interpretar-um-arquivo-json-com-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dessa forma ele vai exibir no seu HTML somente os com level 10 ou maior.

```
<?php foreach ($pets as $pet) : ?>
<?php if($pet['stats']['level']>=10){ ?>
<tr>
    <td> <?php echo $pet['name']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $pet['spellId']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $pet['stats']['level']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $pet['stats']['health']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $pet['stats']['power']; ?> </td>
    <td> <?php echo $pet['stats']['speed']; ?> </td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Esse formato trabalha apenas filtrando os dados que você já recebeu ( full ), talvez na documentação da API, você pode encontrar um parâmetro no qual você consiga passar e receber os dados já filtrados de acordo com a sua necessidade.

Comment: Opa! 
O que voce falou deu certo sim! Muito obrigada.
Agora sobre as "regras" da API, eu pesquisei e eles possuem alguns parametros muito restritos em relação a "filtros" somente consigo filtrar diretamente pela API "specie" e mais alguns outros, mas nada muito detalhado. Mas já me deu uma luz! obrigada!